# Is there a way to prevent mongo queries "branching" on arrays?

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following documents:

```
{a: {x:1}} // without array
{a: [{x:1}]} // with array
```

Is there a way to query for `{'a.x':1}` that will return the first one but not the second one? IE, I want the document where a.x is 1, and a is not an array.

Comment: you would be able to do this in the next version (3.2) with aggregation framework which is getting $isArray operator.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18222

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that [future version of MongoDB would incorporate the `$isArray` aggregation expression](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/52c12e84354e319b1137b1bc7b618dce4396f748). In the meantime...

...the following code will do the trick as the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator matches only documents having an *array* field:

```
> db.test.find({"a.x": 1, "a": {$not: {$elemMatch: {x:1}}}})
```

---

Given that dataset:

```
> db.test.find({},{_id:0})
{ "a" : { "x" : 1 } }
{ "a" : [ { "x" : 1 } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "x" : 0 }, { "x" : 1 } ]
```

It will return:

```
> db.test.find({"a.x": 1, "a": {$not: {$elemMatch: {x:1}}}}, {_id:0})
{ "a" : { "x" : 1 } }
```

---

Please note this should be considered as a short term solution. The MongoDB team took great cares to ensure that `[{x:1}]` and `{x:1}` behave the same (see [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index) or [`$type` for arrays](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays)). So you *should* consider that at some point in the future, `$elemMatch` *might* be updated (see JIRA issue [SERVER-6050](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6050)). In the meantime, maybe worth considering fixing your data model so it would no longer be necessary to distinguish between an array containing one subdocument and a bare subdocument.

Comment: Are there any complications related to indexing using this method?

Comment: I suspect this method may not work in the future - $elemMatch behavior could change as it's been suggested that it should work on subdocuments as well as arrays.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Do you have a pointer to the relevant JIRA issue ? Anyway, I agree that it is not future-proof. Thank you for mentioning that.  I've edited my answer to warn about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding a second term that ensures `a` has no elements. That second term will always be true when `a` is a plain subdoc, and always false when `a` is an array (as otherwise the first term wouldn't have matched).

```js
db.test.find({'a.x': 1, 'a.0': {$exists: false}})
```

Comment: Are there any complications related to indexing using this method?

Comment: You'd want to add an index to `a.x` for the first term. I don't think the second term can use an index, but hopefully you have enough selectivity in the first term that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, but since objects can technically have the key "0", I'm going to go with the other one. +1 tho